# Excluded folders still appear in compiled app?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I excluded some layout folders in Android project via `Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources -> Right-click+Exclude on some layout files`. After this I reloaded the project, compiled it, but the content of excluded layout folders still appears in the running app.

For example, I excluded the folder `layout-large-mdi`, compiled the app, but the content from this folder still appears in the app, instead the content from `/res/layout/` dir.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what that IDE features does for you, but I'm fairly certain it's not intended to prevent the Android build process from including the files.  For that, you'll need to delete the directory or temporarily move it.

Comment: Hm, I thought it is for that purpose as excluded folders do not appear in IDE once you exclude them.

Comment: That's probably what it's for -- to exclude them from the project from the perspective of the IDE.  The Android build system, however, still sees them because they're still on the filesystem in locations that matter to it.

Comment: You are probably right. It's simply a cosmetic feature. Wouldn't be cool to have feature like I thought exclude does?!